# Can one still use AsyncTask with API >= 30?

Tags: android

Since API 30 is AsyncTask deprecated in Android: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask)

Does that mean, that it isn't possible to use it anymore? That using it won't work at all?

Or is the deprecation rather a recommendation? One **should** use Kotlin coroutines instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean, that it isn't possible to use it anymore? That using it won't work at all?

In this case, no.

> Or is the deprecation rather a recommendation?

Frequently, this is the case, and it is the case for `AsyncTask`. If the API no longer works, the documentation will explain what the revised behavior would be.

> One should use Kotlin coroutines instead?

While coroutines are an option, basically Google would prefer that you use just about anything *other* than `AsyncTask`. Depending on circumstances, that could be something like coroutines or RxJava. In other cases, it might be some form of `ExecutorService`. In other cases, it might be `WorkManager`.

Frequently, the deprecation notice will provide recommended alternatives. In this case, it has:

> Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

Here, "the standard java.util.concurrent... utilities" means something like `ExecutorService`, and "Kotlin concurrency utilities" links to coroutines.